# Is this an "example-request" or a "vocabulary" question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've asked a few questions along the lines of "does any word with X properties exist?" For example, [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10999/406) was answered succinctly with ["yes, one example is *glôssa*"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/11000/406).

Should these be considered [example-request](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-request) questions, or [vocabulary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) questions? Or both?

The tag description for [example-request](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-request) seems to be about grammar more than vocabulary, but [vocabulary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) is a synonym for [single-word-translation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-translation), and such questions involve no translation at all.

Comment: When talking about tags, you can write them as `[tag:greek]` to get [tag:greek]. The tag nature is apparent and it's also linkable.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Ah, gratias! Edited.

Comment: I posted the same edit (verbatim!) three seconds after you. That verges on spooky... I did add the [meta-tag:tags], though. (For meta tags, use `[meta-tag:tags]`.)

Answer (score 1):

That question concerns vocabulary, so the tag [vocabulary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) is a good choice.
It also asks for examples, so [example-request](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-request) is also a good fit.
In addition, a good tag would be [greek](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek).

But that'd give you a total of eight tags!
The problem sometimes is that there are so many suitable tags that one has to choose the five best ones.
Whether that means making the questions easy to find, constraining the scope of the question, or something else is for you to choose.

I created the tag [single-word-translation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-translation) with [eradication of the translation tag](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/347/79) in mind.
If a new user comes in and asks a question, they are easily tempted to give the tag [translation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation).
We're getting rid of that tag, but I wanted to arrange so that typing that word gives good tag recommendations.
Therefore I wanted to have a tag containing the string "translation" that would be synonymized with [vocabulary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary).
I realize that this rationale might not be at all apparent when looking at the tags and their descriptions as they are now.

I think the tag [example-request](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-request) should be for all kinds of examples.
That's how I always saw it, but the tag scopes can and will live, so this is not an absolute fact.
The current description is indeed narrower than this.
I suggest rewriting or expanding the description to somehow say "all kinds of example requests".
Examples can be useful, but I don't think the list can be exhaustive in such space.